# nested functions are not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner to JS and I'm working on a leetcode problem; the description of it has been shown below :-

Write a function expect that helps developers test their code. It should take in any value "val" and return an object with the following two functions.

toBe(val) accepts another value and returns true if the two values === each other. If they are not equal, it should throw an error "Not Equal".

notToBe(val) accepts another value and returns true if the two values !== each other. If they are equal, it should throw an error "Equal".

---

The code I have incorporated is shown below :-

```
var expect = function(val) {

function toBe(val2) {
    if (val==val2) {
        return(true);
    } else {
        return("Not Equal");
    }
}

function notToBe(val2) {
    if (val == val2) {
        return("Equal")
    } else {
        return(true);
    } } } 
 
expect(5).toBe(7);
```

and the error I get upon running this code is shown below.

> error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBe')

which is obtained when I call something that hasn't been assigned. I don't know it wrong here because I am using the same syntax from geeksforgeeks. A lot of the leetcode solutions use ":" in their solutions and have a completely different syntax I don't recognize. I will look into the usage of colons in JS. However, I wouls like to know what is wrong with my syntax and code.

Comment: *'...return an object'* is the key part of the description. You are declaring your two functions, but your outer function has no return. Simply add one: `return {toBe, notToBe};`. This return uses [shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#syntax) to declare an object with a property for each of your functions.

Comment: As for semicolons, they are probably [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) which is a strongly typed language built on JavaScript

Comment: @pilchard - Did you mean colons (`:`)? Semicolons (`;`) are JavaScript.

Comment: Colons, yes, typo.

Answer (score 0):

Note the phrase I've highlighted in the description:

> Write a function expect that helps developers test their code. It should take in any value "val" **and return an object with the following two functions**.

The code `expect(5).toBe(7)` expects `expect(5)` to return an object which has a `toBe` property on it, but your `expect` function doesn't return anything. Declaring a function within another function doesn't make the outer function return an object with the inner function as a property; if you want to do that, you have to do it explicitly. For example:

```js
const expect = function (val) {
    function toBe(val2) {
        if (val == val2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return "Not Equal";
        }
    }

    function notToBe(val2) {
        if (val == val2) {
            return "Equal";
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return { toBe, notToBe }; // <== Return an object with the functions as properties
};

console.log(expect(5).toBe(7));
```

Or you could do it using method syntax in the object initializer:

```js
const expect = function (val) {
    return {
        toBe(val2) {
            if (val == val2) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return "Not Equal";
            }
        },

        notToBe(val2) {
            if (val == val2) {
                return "Equal";
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
};

console.log(expect(5).toBe(7));
```

I suggest reading up on [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#objects), ideally in a good tutorial or introductory book. Leetcode problems aren't great for learning the basics of a language.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)